# Python Read Text File Column by Column

Tags: python, file-io, split

So I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1,989785345,"something 1",,234.34,254.123
2,234823423,"something 2",,224.4,254.123
3,732847233,"something 3",,266.2,254.123
4,876234234,"something 4",,34.4,254.123
...
```

I'm running this code right here:

```
file = open("file.txt", 'r')
readFile = file.readline()

lineID = readFile.split(",")
print lineID[1]
```

This lets me break up the content in my text file by "," but what I want to do is separate it into columns because I have a massive number of IDs and other things in each line. How would I go about splitting the text file into columns and call each individual row in the column one by one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a CSV file, use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read it:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
```

This still gives you data by row, but with the `zip()` function you can transpose this to columns instead:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for column in zip(*reader):
```

Do be careful with the latter; the whole file will be read into memory in one go, and a large CSV file *could* eat up all your available memory in the process.

Comment: So what would be an efficient way to read certain columns (say using a list for headers) from a CSV file without loading it all into memory?  I have a huge file with millions of columns and I want to read and use only several hundred at a time. Thank you

Comment: Just process the data as you read it. The `for row in reader:` loop will only need memory for the current row plus a buffer for the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but not sure I follow...  I need to process data by columns, not rows.

Comment: @Confounded: the row contains all columns, so you index the row to get the data for the columns you are interested in. Process that data as you read the rows.

Comment: When I say I need to process data buy columns, I mean that I need to have the whole column before I can start processing.  If I understood you correctly, I would need to read the whole file using `for row` approach to do that.

Comment: @Confounded: if you can only process the column *as a whole* you have little choice but to read the whole column. You don't have to keep the other columns in this process however. `zip()` is a shortcut here, you can also use `[row[index] for row in reader]` to build a list with a single column from the file.

Comment: @Confounded: it is rare that you need the whole column in memory to achieve what you want, however.

Comment: What about `seek()`? Can this be used to skip to columns that are required?  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded: not trivially, not unless your columns are of a fixed length. Otherwise, you can't know where to seek *to* in order to read the right column from each line. And that won't solve the problem of holding all data for the column in memory.